# How to setup username and password in redis?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-cluster, infrastructure

Tying to setup username and password for redis (6). Have seen some documentation that helps setting up a password for redis. Is there a way I can set both the username and password?

Comment: Take a look at [Redis ACL](https://redis.io/docs/manual/security/acl/)

Answer (score 2):

For Redis 6 and above, the recommended way to create users is to use the Redis Access Control List (ACL).

You create (and modify) a user with the [`acl setuser`](https://redis.io/commands/acl-setuser/) command together with a number of rules that you want to apply to the user. A rule is either a **command rule** or a **user management rule**.

Read more about the rules you can apply to a user [here](https://redis.io/commands/acl-setuser/).

Example: `acl setuser redis_user >redis_password on allchannels allkeys +get +set +del`

- `redis_user`: The username.
- `>redis_password`: Adds password `redis_password` to user. A user can have more then one password.
- `on`: User is enabled. Use `off` to disable a user.
- `allchannels`: Allows the user to access all pub/sub channels.
- `allkeys`: Allows the user to access all the keys.
- `+get +set +del`: Allows the user to use the commands in the list. A `-` before the command removes the permission. Besides commands (`+`/`-`) you can also use categories (`+@`/`-@`) which are groups of commands. Use command `acl cat` to list all categories and `acl cat <CATEGORY>` to list all commands for a specific category.

If you try to run a command that is not permitted you'll get the following error: `(error) NOPERM User redis_user has no permissions to run the 'mset' command`.

Use `redis-cli --user redis_user --pass redis_password` to log in with the new user.